# how to customize tab position in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, ios, tabs, xamarin.ios

I have gone through with this link [xamarin tabs link](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tab_bar/create_a_tab_bar/) for applying the tabs in my xamarin IOS application. and tabs has been successfully applied but i need this tabs should appear on the top of the application's header part.but I have not found any method or property for adjusts the tabs position. So Please help me , and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apples [Human Interface Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Bars.html)s specify that a Tab Bar should always appear at the bottom edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a **UIToolbar** instead of **UITabBar**, you can position it at design time at the desired location, and add **UIButton** or any other **UIBarItems**.

Hope this helps.