# how to apply tabs on top of the Page in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, tabbar

I am creating an application in Xamarin IOS , I need a navigation bar as well on the top of the screen and just below the navigation bar I need 3 buttons in Tabs(The Tabs button will do the some DB stuff accordingly).

I am able to add successfully the navigation bar on top in C# but unable to add 3 buttons in tabs. I have not found any useful tutorial till now on xamarin documentation. So please help me, it will be Much Appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to customize tab position in xamarin ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879194/how-to-customize-tab-position-in-xamarin-ios)

Comment: You asked the same question 2 days ago, and the answer is the same - Apple requires Tabs to be at the bottom of the screen.  If you insist on having them at the top of the screen, you will need to use some alternate control - a UIButton, a UISegmentedControl, a toolbar, etc.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?